# "ob_flush(): failed to flush buffer. No buffer to flush" on production Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, server-sent-events

I am working on Server Sent Event in laravel. I am getting error on production "ob_flush(): failed to flush buffer. No buffer to flush" its working fine on localhost but throwing error on production

here is the sse code

```
 public function notificationsCount(Request $request)
{
    try {
        $response = new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\StreamedResponse(function () use ($request) {

            while (true) {
                $notif_count = Auth::user()->unreadNotifications->count();
                echo json_encode(['data' => $notif_count]) . "\n\n";
                ob_flush();
                flush();
                sleep(1);

                if (connection_aborted()) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            ob_end_flush();
        });
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/event-stream');
        $response->headers->set('X-Accel-Buffering', 'no');
        $response->headers->set('Cach-Control', 'no-cache');
        return $response->send();
    } catch (\Exception$e) {
        return response()->json(['error' => $e->getMessage()]);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You only need `ob_flush()` if an output buffer is active (for example by `ob_start()`, or by php.ini settings)

try

```
  ob_start();
  echo "foo";
  ob_flush();
```

Comment: past her `ob_get_level()` please

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-level.php